# Delayed Variable enpansion and content replacement

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to parse a table in a text file, reorder some columns and make little modifications. I use the FOR loop in a BAT file of the command processor.

```
echo Header line > outfile.txt

rem get each line from infile.txt but skip first two columns
FOR /f "tokens=3,4*" %%a IN (infile.txt) DO call :handle_line %%a %%b
goto :eof

:handle_line
set a=%1
set b=%2
set b=%b:FOO=BAR%
echo %2 %1 >>outfile.txt
goto :eof
```

This works so far but it is slow. I want to use the other FOR loop Syntax

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "tokens=3,4*" %%a IN (infile.txt) DO (
    set cA=%%a
    set cB=%%b
    set cB=%cb:FOO=BAR%
    set cBB=!cb:FOO=BAR!

    echo %cB% %cA% %cBB%>>outfile.txt
)
```

The problem is that the Content FOO is not replaced by BAR. Neither with `%%` nor `!!`. How should I use the content replacement when I use the `FOR IN DO ()` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
set cBB=!cb:FOO=BAR!
```

is working, but you need to change all occurrences
of `%variable[:modifier]optional%` to use `!…!`;
specifically, you need to

```
echo !cB! !cA! !cBB!
```